# windows-rs: How am I supposed to create an `IDataObject`?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I'm using the `windows` crate and trying to follow [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20170924112501/http://www.catch22.net/tuts/drag-and-drop-introduction) to create a drag and drop button on Windows.
Now my question is: How am I supposed to create an [`IDataObject`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Com/struct.IDataObject.html). I can't find a `new` or `create` function to initialize one.

Comment: You do not create an `IDataObject` as this is an interface. You either receive one or you create an object that implements it. As your tutorial says: _ Creating these two objects is non-trivial and is therefore covered in the next section of this tutorial._

Comment: Yes, I read that too but I thought, since `IDataObject` is a struct, it is already implemented. I guess I have to create my own struct and implement the `IDataObject_Impl` trait.

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding: you implement the `IDataObject_Impl` trait and then you get the `IDataObject` value, that is a COM pointer wrapper, for it, using `.into()` just like in this [example](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/crates/samples/core_app/src/main.rs#L67).

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense.